# Covid19 rapid antigen test in Sweden for foreigners

Tags: covid-19, sweden

I am a non-Swedish EU citizen travelling in Sweden. To return to my home country, I require a negative Covid19 rapid antigen test. Is it easy got get tested and what are the costs?

Comment: Have you tried searching for this information eg ‘Covid tests in Sweden’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty easy, even if many places require a booked appointment. Price is 400-1500 SEK. Here is a comparison site (not sure if it is complete though) https://pcrpriser.se/en